# Validated Textbox in a UserControl

Tags: wpf, validation, user-controls, textbox, adornerdecorator

I have created a UserControl - a Labeled `TextBox` which is working pretty well, except for the validation template. When there's an error the validation control template shows up but it fills the whole space including the Label. I only want it to be as big as the `TextBox`. How to fix this?

Here's the xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Infrastructure.CustomControls.LabelTextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Name="LTB">

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{Binding}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock x:Name="tbl" 
                   FontFamily="{Binding}" 
                   FontSize="{Binding}" 
                   Text="{Binding ElementName=LTB, Path=LabelText}" 
                   Height="{Binding ElementName=LTB, Path=LabelHeight}" 
                   Width="{Binding ElementName=LTB, Path=LabelWidth}" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbx" 
                 Grid.Column="1" 
                 FontFamily="{Binding}" 
                 FontSize="{Binding}" 
                 IsReadOnly="{Binding ElementName=LTB, Path=IsReadOnly}" 
                 MaxLength="{Binding ElementName=LTB, Path=TextMaxLength}" 
                 Text="{Binding ElementName=LTB, Path=Text}" 
                 Height="{Binding ElementName=LTB, Path=TextHeight}"
                 Width="{Binding ElementName=LTB, Path=TextWidth}" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" 
                               ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=aep, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                                   Foreground="Red" 
                                   FontSize="14pt" Text="*" 
                                   Margin="-15,0,0,0" 
                                   FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="aep"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: what happens if set Width="{Binding ElementName=tbx, Path=ActualWidth}" for DockPanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response, it helped me figure out where the problem is. And for that i vote it as useful.

What i did was programmatically query the UserControl validation for errors in the `TextBoxChangedEvent` and set the validation error manually (http://wpftutorial.net/ValidationErrorByCode.html) for the `TextBox`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this happens is that you're implementing `IDataErrorInfo` in your view and not your UserControl. This causes the *default* WPF red border to appear for the entire usercontrol.

To get your defined error template to appear, you'll need to implement `IDataErrorInfo` in your usercontrol and add `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True` to your binding expression.

If you'd like to keep the `IDataErrorInfo` logic in your view and not in your UserControl (which is pretty reasonable), you'll need to define a validation template for the user control in the view:

```
<Window>
    <local:UserControl>
        <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate>
                ...
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
    </local:UserControl>
</Window>
```

To get it to only show the border for the TextBox, you can play with the border's width using a converter that'll take the entire usercontrol's width as a parameter and return the width of the textbox; possibly something like this:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Width="{Binding ElementName=ph, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}">
    <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="ph" />
</Border>
```